# Django only translating one word

Tags: django, localization, internationalization

I am attempting a navbar translation to simplified Chinese in Django, however, only the first word is being translated. To wit, I have created a `navbar.html` with the following content:

```
{% load i18n %}
<li><a href="{% url 'homepage' %}">{% trans 'Home' %}</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'security' %}">{% trans 'Security' %}</a></li>
```

I then do a `./manage.py makemessages -l zh_CN` and constructed a file `django.po` which contains

```
#: templates/navbar.html:20
msgid "Home"
msgstr "首页"

#: templates/navbar.html:25
msgid "Security"
msgstr "安全性"
```

I then did a `./manage.py compilemessages` to get the `django.mo`, which appears to have all the translations I need.

As opposed to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234842/django-only-a-single-element-gets-translated#18252801), my `LOCALE_PATHS` is indeed a tuple:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

and my `LocaleMiddleware` is after `SessionMiddleware` and before `CommonMiddleware`, as the documentation specifies:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Yet nonetheless, only `Home` is translated; all other template variables are left untranslated.

To add a bit more mystery, I translated the navbar to Spanish and all variable were translated properly in the browser. This made me suspect my browser was not using the correct language code, so I ran `./manage.py makemessages -l zh-hans` and copied over the translation from the `zh_CN` directory, but no dice.

Following [this](http://blog.e-shell.org/124), I have removed all instances of `#, fuzzy`, to no avail.

I am on Django 1.10.3 and Python 3.5.

Comment: why not using `zh-hans` directly? for my project, i use `zh-hans`, and it work perfectly...

Comment: I used `zh_CN` because that's what `django-registration` uses. I removed it at your advice and only used `zh-hans`, and the problem did not go away.